# How to serialize a YamlNode graph?

Tags: yamldotnet

YamlDotNet seems to support serializing POC graphs, but I can't find an API that serializes an object graph made directly of YamlNode types. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to pass the root node into a new `YamlDocument` and then to pass the document to `YamlStream`, which exposes a `Save` method.

```
var rootNode = new YamlMappingNode();
rootNode.Add("methods", methods);
var result = new YamlDocument(rootNode);
var resultStream = new YamlStream(result);
using var resultWriter = File.CreateText(@"d:\temp\scraped.yml");
resultStream.Save(resultWriter);
```